# MySQL database wrong column encoding?

Tags: mysql

I have a column that is using the encoding cp1252 West and often it's recording data like this:

```
Diá»n ÄÃ n Minecraft Viá»t Nam
```

Should I change this to UTF-8, or some other encoding, and will that fix the problem? I have a lot of text from foreign websites often.

What do you recommend?

Comment: I would make a backup of the database and try:

`ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: Using utf8 (actually utf8mb4) would be advisable, but changing the column in place is unlikely to fix all your existing data. See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) -- even if your application is not PHP, the same concepts apply.

Comment: I'm not too worried about the data as it's just metadata that has been collected of some various sites. I could even CURL them again if I had to. Yes, I'll take a backup and try and convert to character set - that's some good tips thanks guys...

Comment: @AmyNeville did that work?